# Haskell: Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from the literal ‘1’ from the context (Num a)

Tags: haskell

Creating a simple multiplier using recursion, GHCI raise an error on the function type

```
mul :: Num a => a -> a -> a
mul a 1 = a
mul a n = a + mul a (n-1)
```

This is the error message received

```
Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from the literal ‘1’
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the type signature for mul :: Num a => a -> a -> a
  at es8.hs:44:8-27
Possible fix:
  add (Eq a) to the context of
    the type signature for mul :: Num a => a -> a -> a
In the pattern: 1
In an equation for ‘mul’: mul a 1 = a
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I think I must apply Number object with params so the `Num a` part is mandatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This constraint comes for the first equation you used to define `mul`:

```
mul a 1 = a
```

It says that whenever the second argument *equals* `1` the result should be the first argument. `Num` does not have an `Eq` superclass constraint because it's possible to think of numbers for which equality is not decidable (e.g. the Reals). So you need, as suggested by the error message, to restrict your function further by adding that constraint by hand.

```
mul :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
mul a 1 = a
mul a n = a + mul a (n-1)
```

Comment: I would add that it should maybe be `Integral` instead of `Num` - consider what `mul 3 2.5` is going to do.

Comment: `Integral` by itself won't fix the problem for `mul 3 0`.